# \r help in PHP -- interpretation error

Tags: php

I am writing a code in PHP and line is as follows

```
$xml_output .= "\t\t\t<\report-paper_metadata>\n";
```

As u can see that i am trying 2 output

```
<\report-paper_metadata>
```

But PHP is reading it as `\r` feed ..

```
                                 <eport-paper_metadata>
```

I dont want to declare using a variable and use it..

any suggestion on how overcome this??

Any questions plzzz comment..

Comment: By the way, XML and HTML tags always close with a forward slash, not a backwards slash.  Are you absolutely certain that shouldn't be </report-paper_metadata>?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\r` is a special character, just like `\n`. Use `\\r` instead (double slash).

Answer (score 3):

Escape the slash:

```
$xml_output .= "\t\t\t<\\report-paper_metadata>\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to escape it, e.g. `\\r`.

If you were not relying on other special characters, you could also use single quotes (`'`) which treats each character literally in the string.

Special characters are interpreted in double quotes (`"`) only (and HEREDOC and NOWDOC).

Comment: that would kill ``\t`` and ``\n``.

Answer (score 2):

use double `\` like `\\` and it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `\r` with an extra `\`:

```
$xml_output .= "\t\t\t<\\report-paper_metadata>\n";
```

Or better separate formatting and data:

```
$xml_output .= "\t\t\t".'<\report-paper_metadata>'."\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if not a nice solution but just to be exhaustive keeping double quotes you also can use concatenation of string just like that: `$xml_output .= "\t\t\t".'<\report-paper_metadata>'."\n";`

I admit it's not nice at all ;) @alex answers is the most complete one imho